# zend framework 2 performance: time, memory and cpu

Tags: performance, zend-framework2

So here's a thing. I have 8GB RAM and 8 core CPU on my dev laptop.
After deploying website on Amazon EC2 small instance (1.7 GB RAM and 1 virtual core with 1 EC2 Compute Unit) I was unpleasantly surprised to know that instead of decent ~200ms a heavy page now is generated for ~600ms.

Of course I profiled this and other pages but just, it seems everything works slower. Nothing particular longer than others. This page consumes about 12.5 MB of memory which I believe should have no difference if it's 8GB or just 1.7 in general!

Can smb give me a clue why on though a weaker but (I believe) more than satisfying configuration PHP works out slower in ~3 times in general?!

Comment: This may be a topic better server over at http://serverfault.com/ 600ms is a speed i have on local development (windows xampp) and moving the code to producting im at roughly 150, which is acceptable. Locally, it's 80% the DB connection that slows me down.

Comment: Yea maybe it's better to raise this question on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: See, I have vice versa situation. And I know for sure DB is not a bottle neck

Answer (score 0):

One improvement is to build a class map when you deploy to live, rather than using the usual class loader, this can bring a big improvement

If you have used composer to setup (you should) then you can get composer to generate a class map for you:

```
 php composer.phar dump-autoload -o
```

see here for doing using Zend Tool: https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool

```
zf.php classmap generate <directory> <classmap file> [--append|-a] [--overwrite|-w]
```

I would include it as part of your deployment process. Also make sure you've got some kind of opcode caching as there can be a huge number of files included for each request.

Comment: Yea, I created classmap using `vendor/zendframework/zendframework/bin/classmap_generator.php` It includes **5992 classes**, maybe it's too much?! 

Also I have **APC** installed

Comment: Nevertheless, as I mentioned any page just works out ~3x longer.